# Cannot see Theme App Extension in theme builder

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-api

Hi Have developed a very simply Theme App extension for Shopify but cannot see it in the Shopify theme builder.

Files are:

/extensions/myextension/blocks/app-block.liquid

Hello world

```
{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Test",
    "target": "section",
    "templates": ["product", "index"],
    "settings": [
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

/extensions/myextension/shopify.theme.extension.toml

```
name = "myextension"
type = "theme"
```

I then run npm run dev which runs as expected, I can also the extension under the Apps section in my Shopify admin, but cannot see any blocks for it in the theme editor.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Quick troubleshooting guide:

1. Have you built and deployed your extension using CLI?
2. Did you enabled preview in partner panel? You can try setting up an initial version.
3. Is your theme 2.0 theme? You should be able to use your component on the homepage.